# Highstock, how to offset all Y data from a serie on clicking range selector buttons

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart containing two panes (so 2 series). The first serie show some height data in millimeters at different dates and the second serie show the same dates but cumulating the heights taken from serie 1. Here is a simplified example of my data:

**serie 1:**
    [[1373313300000.0, 0.4], [1373313900000.0, 0.6], [1373314500000.0, 1], [1373315100000.0, 0.2], [1373315700000.0, 0.6], [1373316300000.0, 0.8]]

**serie 2:**
    [[1373313300000.0, 0.4], [1373313900000.0, 1.0], [1373314500000.0, 2.0], [1373315100000.0, 2.2], [1373315700000.0, 2.8], [1373316300000.0, 3.6]]

What I want to do is to restart the cumulated values from serie 2 to 0 when user click on any button on the range selectors (zoom buttons i.e. 1d, 1w, 1m, all, etc...). So if user pick a range like 1day, 1 week or anything else, he should see the first height from serie 2 = 0 and other values following after that the normal summing pattern...

My question is:  What would be the correct way to modify dynamically my Y data from serie 2 to restart it to 0 and create that "offset" down of the entire serie? Is there any way to specify an offset value to put down an entire serie or do I have to iterate over my entire serie and alter my datas 1 by 1?

Also in what event should I trigger that changes? In the setExtremes event of xaxis?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

For sure you need to use [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) event handler.

Then you need to set new data for second series which will be accumulated from beginning. Yes, you need to loop over all points ( within specific timerange ), compute new values, and then set data.

Comment: I iterate over myChart.series[0].points and create a new array with Y value offsetted without problem... However, doing myChart.series[0].setData(myNewArrayOfData) trigger again the afterSetExtremes event and enter an infinite loop... There should be a better way to do that no?

Comment: And if I try updating the existing points 1 by 1 instead of creating a new serie with something like: myChart.series[0].points[i].update(5, false), the chart is not refreshed so my changes are not applied... If I do a redraw my changes seems to be discarded... There is definitively something I don't understand on this data modification process...

Comment: Infinite loop? Hmm.. in that case add some flag like: `loop = false; ..setData(newData); loop = true;` and then in afterSetExtremes check for loop: `if(loop) { .. do calculations .. } else { .. do nothing .. }`.

Comment: The `loop` guard worked for me, but it seems this is something the library should prevent.

Comment: In first place, it shouldn't happen when setting data (`setData()` method). I don't think we should guard this - if user uses explicite `setExtremes()`, then user should guard this infinite loop.